Google Apps Script only works for me
I've used the following script to automatically sort entries in a Google Sheet but it only works for me. When another user, with whom I've shared the Google Sheet, edits the sheet the sorting is not triggered. They've not been asked/prompted to grant authority to run the script using their account. I'm not sure what I need to change to make it work and/or prompt the user to grant authority.
 function onEdit(e){
  var w = e.source.getSheetByName("Assignments");//Replace Assignments with the name of the worksheet you want to sort in
  var srtby = 12; //Change this to the position of the col you want to sort by
  var srtby2 = 6; //Change this to the position of the col you want to second sort by
  var t = "A2:L"; // Change this to range of cells that you want to sort (don't include the column headings).
  var range = w.getRange(t);
    range.sort([
      { column : srtby, ascending: true }, //change false to true if you want to sort in ascending order.
        { column : srtby2, ascending: true }]);//change false to true if you want to sort in ascending order
  }

Tried to use Apps Script to sort the entries in a Google Sheet when it is edited.
Works for me but not for anyone else editing the Google Sheet.

[Edit] to post debugging information - specifically, Executions tab would show the error at the specific time they edited.. See [mcve]

I tried replicating your issue, shared it to another account, there is also no Consent Screen that showed up however the other account was able to trigger the onEdit can you provide what TheMaster is asking, and also if what are the overall steps you took for this?


They've not been asked/prompted to grant authority to run the script using their account.

The code in the question is a simple trigger that requires no authorization. It will work the same regardless of who edits the spreadsheet, but may error out in the event there are protected cells in the edited tab.
Check My Executions for failed executions, and view those logs to learn more about why the function fails.
Remove any offending protections to avoid the errors. See Protect a range or sheet.

Thank you! I hadn't given protected cells a second thought. All works now! Thanks again.

I gather that this is your first question at Stack Overflow. See What should I do when someone answers my question?
